# Add an animation to a Show/Hide Checked Box

Tags: javascript

I use this javascrpit code to show/hide a div when a specific checkbox is checked

```
$(function() {
 $('input[name=choice1]').on('click init-choice1', function() {
  $('#delivery').toggle($('#store').prop('checked'));
 }).trigger('init-choice1');
});
```

How can I add an animation to my *delivery* div when the *choice1* checkbox is checked ?

Here an actual exemple of what result I have without animation : https://jsfiddle.net/6h4u3a1b/

Thanks in advance,
~Quentin

Comment: Perhaps any of these would be help for you https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do, for example:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $(function() {
      $('input[name=choice1]').on('click init-choice1', function() {
          if ($('#store').prop('checked')) $('#delivery').fadeIn();
          else $('#delivery').fadeOut(); 
     }).trigger('init-choice1');
 });
})
```

or instead of the "if ..." simply:

```
$('#delivery').fadeToggle();
```

This will show a little flicker at the beginnig so you youd have to add this style rule to prevent it:

```
.two { display: none }
```

Replace fadeIn/fadeOut with slideUp/slideDown for a different animation our use jQuery's animate() function to animate whatever CSS rule you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution: Hope it helps!

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
 $("#delivery").hide();
  $(function() {
      $('input[name=choice1]').on('click init-choice1', function() {
          if ($('#store').prop('checked')) $('#delivery').fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(200, 1.0);
          else $('#delivery').fadeOut(); 
     }).trigger('init-choice1');
 });
})
```

```html
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="one">
  <p>
    <input name="choice1" type="radio" id="download" checked  />
    <label for="download">Download</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="choice1" type="radio" id="store"  />
    <label for="store">Store</label>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="two" id="delivery">
  <p>
    <input name="choice2" type="radio" id="x"  />
    <label for="x">Add to X</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="choice2" type="radio" id="y"  />
    <label for="y">Add to Y</label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to you too :)

Comment: I did it but I have this message :
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"